# Oracle Session activity Last 10 seconds

Tags: oracle

I want to transform this query to the last 10 seconds instead of last hours

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLE_TIME, 'HH24:MI ') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
       ROUND(OTHER / 60, 3) AS OTHER,
       ROUND(CLUST / 60, 3) AS CLUST,
       ROUND(QUEUEING / 60, 3) AS QUEUEING,
       ROUND(NETWORK / 60, 3) AS NETWORK,
       ROUND(ADMINISTRATIVE / 60, 3) AS ADMINISTRATIVE,
       ROUND(CONFIGURATION / 60, 3) AS CONFIGURATION,
       ROUND(COMMIT / 60, 3) AS COMMIT,
       ROUND(APPLICATION / 60, 3) AS APPLICATION,
       ROUND(CONCURRENCY / 60, 3) AS CONCURRENCY,
       ROUND(SIO / 60, 3) AS SYSTEM_IO,
       ROUND(UIO / 60, 3) AS USER_IO,
       ROUND(SCHEDULER / 60, 3) AS SCHEDULER,
       ROUND(CPU / 60, 3) AS CPU,
       ROUND(BCPU / 60, 3) AS BACKGROUND_CPU
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'MI') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
               DECODE(SESSION_STATE,
                      'ON CPU',
                      DECODE(SESSION_TYPE, 'BACKGROUND', 'BCPU', 'ON CPU'),
                      WAIT_CLASS) AS WAIT_CLASS
          FROM V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY
         WHERE SAMPLE_TIME > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1'HOUR AND SAMPLE_TIME <= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MI')) ASH PIVOT(COUNT(*) 
  FOR WAIT_CLASS IN('ON CPU' AS CPU,'BCPU' AS BCPU,'Scheduler' AS SCHEDULER,'User I/O' AS UIO,'System I/O' AS SIO, 'Concurrency' AS CONCURRENCY, 
'Application' AS  APPLICATION,COMMIT,                                                                             
'Configuration' AS CONFIGURATION,                     
'Administrative' AS   ADMINISTRATIVE,                                                                                 
'Network' AS  NETWORK,                                                                                 
'Queueing' AS   QUEUEING,                                                                                  
'Cluster' AS   CLUST,                                                                                      
'Other' AS  OTHER))
ORDER BY 1
```

I tried using this  WHERE SAMPLE_TIME > SYSDATE - (10)/(24*60*60)
but it's not working. It gives me the result in minute. But I want the last 10 seconds (so 10 lines)

Comment: The query as posted is syntactically incorrect; if you had one that works, what happened - *copy and paste* not working? The error is in the `IN` list of the `PIVOT` clause: you have **COMMIT** in the list. That should be `'Commit' as COMMIT`.

Comment: The query is working in my db

Comment: Then it may not be Oracle? COMMIT as you have it in the list (not enclosed in single quotes) is interpreted as a column name - which is illegal in an `IN` list. The `IN` list can only contain constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the outer select list to include the seconds:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLE_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
```

You need to remove the minute-level truncation from the inner query select list:

```
  FROM (SELECT SAMPLE_TIME,
```

You need to change the sample time filter (as the column is a timestamp, might as well use `systimestamp` and an interval so it stays as one):

```
         WHERE SAMPLE_TIME > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' SECOND
  )
  ASH PIVOT(COUNT(*)
```

And as noted in comments your `COMMIT` should be `'Commit' as COMMIT`, otherwise you get "ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values", at least in 11gR2, 12cR1 and 12cR2; and you need to supply the actual `wait_class` name as it appears in the ASH view anyway.

With those changes the query seems to do what you want. It won't necessarily show 10 rows though, as there may not have been samples every second; e.g. on a very quiet DB I usually get no rows or only a few.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLE_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS ') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
       ROUND(OTHER / 60, 3) AS OTHER,
       ROUND(CLUST / 60, 3) AS CLUST,
       ROUND(QUEUEING / 60, 3) AS QUEUEING,
       ROUND(NETWORK / 60, 3) AS NETWORK,
       ROUND(ADMINISTRATIVE / 60, 3) AS ADMINISTRATIVE,
       ROUND(CONFIGURATION / 60, 3) AS CONFIGURATION,
       ROUND(COMMIT / 60, 3) AS COMMIT,
       ROUND(APPLICATION / 60, 3) AS APPLICATION,
       ROUND(CONCURRENCY / 60, 3) AS CONCURRENCY,
       ROUND(SIO / 60, 3) AS SYSTEM_IO,
       ROUND(UIO / 60, 3) AS USER_IO,
       ROUND(SCHEDULER / 60, 3) AS SCHEDULER,
       ROUND(CPU / 60, 3) AS CPU,
       ROUND(BCPU / 60, 3) AS BACKGROUND_CPU
  FROM (SELECT SAMPLE_TIME AS SAMPLE_TIME,
             DECODE(SESSION_STATE,
                    'ON CPU',
                    DECODE(SESSION_TYPE, 'BACKGROUND', 'BCPU', 'ON CPU'),
                    WAIT_CLASS) AS WAIT_CLASS
          FROM V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY
         WHERE SAMPLE_TIME > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' second
  ) ASH
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*) 
  FOR WAIT_CLASS IN ('ON CPU' AS CPU,
    'BCPU' AS BCPU,
    'Scheduler' AS SCHEDULER,
    'User I/O' AS UIO,
    'System I/O' AS SIO,
    'Concurrency' AS CONCURRENCY, 
    'Application' AS  APPLICATION,
    'Commit' as COMMIT,
    'Configuration' AS CONFIGURATION,
    'Administrative' AS   ADMINISTRATIVE,
    'Network' AS  NETWORK,
    'Queueing' AS   QUEUEING,
    'Cluster' AS   CLUST,
    'Other' AS  OTHER)
)
ORDER BY 1  
/
```

```
SAMPLE_TI      OTHER      CLUST   QUEUEING    NETWORK ADMINISTRATIVE CONFIGURATION     COMMIT APPLICATION CONCURRENCY  SYSTEM_IO    USER_IO  SCHEDULER        CPU BACKGROUND_CPU
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
17:57:26           0          0          0          0              0             0          0           0           0          0          0          0       .017              0
```